# Getting [object Object] how can I print each value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am defining a variable called user. The session storage gets the value of that variable as [object Object], but if I try to get or print different properties I get the following

```
user.name = I get nothing 
user[0] = I get [
```

I have tried different ways but I am not able to get the property of that object called name.

Help please!

```
sessionStorage.user = userSessionStorage;
```

I get [object Object]

I just need to know how I can get the values of the differents properties

Comment: show your code please

Comment: add what you have tried in question

Comment: you may use  JSON.stringify(object) to get values.

Comment: DId not work. I am still getting [object Object]

Comment: @KenethSmith did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different reason why user.name returns undefined. Firstly, `name` property might not exist in your `user` object. You can do that by doing this:

```
Object.keys(user)
```

and see if the string `name` is in the output array.

Once you have done that, You can try looping through the properties of `user` like so:

```
Object.keys(user).forEach(e => console.log(e + ' = ' + user[e]));
```

Comment: I got this Error: user.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

From the `session storage` you will get a `string`, you need to make use of `JSON.parse()` before getting the value

```
var usr = JSON.parse(user);
console.log(usr)  // this will log the object from where you can access the properties.
```

Comment: I got JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Press CTRL + SHIFT + J to open the Chrome developer tools and then you will be able to see the result you get from your session storage. Can you post that

Answer (score 0):

Set the data as a `JSON String` in session Storage instead of `JSON Object`.

```
var userData = JSON.stringify(userSessionStorage);

sessionStorage.setItem("user", userData);
```

And parse it again to `JSON Object` from `JSON String` when you get back from the storage.

```
var getUser = sessionStorage.getItem("user");

var user = JSON.parse(getUser);
```